# checking a if directory exists, Concenating variable with path?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I was making a program/installer, and I needed to check if a directory exists under - C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Appdata and so on. The two % won't work, I guess that's only in batch. So I tried another way

EDIT!!

So I revamped my code and still an error, this time you can see all my code, I know its in-efficient. Thank you!

> Public Class Form1

```
Dim reflex As Boolean
Dim nodus As Boolean
Dim rinstalled As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles install.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        If reflex = True Then
            Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat")
        End If
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        If nodus = True Then
            Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dlclient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dlclient.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1644.mediafire.com/s111t3phtatg/bqsuh8c4f2n8w99/Reflex.jar", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.jar")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download763.mediafire.com/93aqmg62kvqg/5jfpe65usw3tajw/Reflex.json", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.json")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download939.mediafire.com/cr8u67j6ce3g/60ewsmp3l35e1mt/installReflex.bat", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat")
        status.ForeColor = Color.Green
        status.Text = "Client Downloaded!"
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download903.mediafire.com/qmqiiyb1128g/6q6libdtwvgp0kt/NodusLauncher.jar", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.jar")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1835.mediafire.com/4w9bh91tf9qg/ug7jsnj0gkxu2gp/NodusLauncher.json", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.json")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1346.mediafire.com/ecje8cg9wdug/uqm37mk1k4qxi59/installNodus.bat", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat")
        status.ForeColor = Color.Green
        status.Text = "Client Downloaded!"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    Timer2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.jar") Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.json") Then
                If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat") Then
                    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\AppData\.minecraft\versions\Reflex") Then
                        install.Enabled = False
                        dlclient.Text = "Client installed"
                    Else
                        reflex = True
                        status.ForeColor = Color.Green
                        status.Text = "Client Downloaded!"
                        dlclient.Enabled = False
                        install.Enabled = True
                        dlclient.Text = "Client Already Downloaded"
                    End If
                Else
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.json")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.jar")
                End If
            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.jar")
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat")
            End If
        Else
            If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.json") Then
                If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\Reflex.json")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Reflex\installReflex.bat")
                End If
            Else
                dlclient.Enabled = True
                install.Enabled = False
                status.ForeColor = Color.Red
                status.Text = "Client not downloaded"
                dlclient.Text = "Download Client"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.jar") Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.json") Then
                If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat") Then
                    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\AppData\.minecraft\versions\NodusLauncher") Then
                        install.Enabled = False
                        dlclient.Text = "Client Installed"
                        status.Text = "Client Installed"
                    Else
                        nodus = True
                        status.ForeColor = Color.Green
                        status.Text = "Client Downloaded!"
                        dlclient.Enabled = False
                        install.Enabled = True
                    End If
                Else
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.json")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.jar")
                End If
            Else
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.jar")
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat")
            End If
        Else
            If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.json") Then
                If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat") Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\NodusLauncher.json")
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\MCHaxor\bin\clients\1.8\Nodus\installNodus.bat")
                End If
            Else
                dlclient.Enabled = True
                install.Enabled = False
                status.ForeColor = Color.Red
                status.Text = "Client not downloaded"
                dlclient.Text = "Download Client"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    about.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Your if condition is wrong, you can't have a "." (period) in a directory name like you have...for example (AppData\.minecraft) is invalid

Comment: start by using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` rather than a string literal.  why is this going in in a Timer event?

Comment: This is going in a timer event because I'm a newb and I needed somehow to check if a directory existed all the time, (there's probably a better way). Also, can you demonstrate on how to use the environment.getFolderPath, I'm still a little new to coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment above, your directory you are checking is wrong because it contains an invalid character for the directory name...

```
 '**.minecraft is invalid for a directory name...**
  If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\AppData\.minecraft") Then
        status.Text = "Client Installed"
        install.Enabled = False
    End If
```

**EDIT** 
I wasn't aware of the beginning period and yes this is a valid path. I just tested this again with the created folders as you have and it works just fine. Not sure what else you have going on?

Comment: Hi! I cannot change the directory name because this is a standard for minecraft, but thank you!

Comment: The answer stay's as I have mentioned. I was able to create the same directories as you and it worked just fine. Is there anything else you may be leaving out. Again, I created a folder ".minecraft\versions\Reflex" and it did come back as it was there. I removed the last folder and did the check again and it failed... This above does indeed work...

Comment: @ePlays the answer I provided does work. Accepting an answer and removing it doesn't justify anything besides you saying it doesn't work. The directory structures are the same so maybe you have left something out?

Comment: I didnt remove an answer mate, Did I did indeed try your code, Did you see if the button gets disabled when the timer ticks that it found the reflex directory? Thank you again!

Comment: Also, I changed my code, you can see all of it now, if that gives you a better understanding, Thanks